# Deleting core data element

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to implement a feature to delete flash cards in a deck of custom flash cards, but am having trouble with the CoreData side of it. What this is supposed to do is loop through the saved cards, and if it matches with the desired card to be deleted, then we'll remove it from the current deck and save the context, anyone know what's going wrong? using break points I can confirm that the if statement does execute, so it has the be the logic inside

```
do {
    self.fetchedCards = try context.fetch(Cards.fetchRequest())
    for card in self.fetchedCards {
        if(self.termLabel.text == card.term){
        self.managedDeck?.removeFromCards(card)
        ad.saveContext()
        break
        }
     }
 } catch {
   }
```

Comment: Removing an object from a relationship does not delete the object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in the `if` statement, I needed `context.delete(card)` instead of `self.managedDeck?.removeFromCards(card)`

Answer (score 2):

Please use this function to delete all the data from the core data

```
func deleteAllData(entity: String) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        for managedObject in results
        {
            let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject
            managedContext.deleteObject(managedObjectData)
            print("Deleted")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for delete the all data you can use this function

```
func deleteAllData(entity: String) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do
    {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        for managedObject in results
        {
            let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject
            managedContext.deleteObject(managedObjectData)
            print("Deleted")
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

USAGE :

```
deleteAllData(entity: "your Entity name")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var cards = try! context.fetch(Cards.fetchRequest())

for card in cards {
    if (self.termLabel.text == card.term) {
        context.delete(card)
    }
}
try! context.save()
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide an explanation why and how your answer solves the problem.